# Updating several text objects in matplotlib simultaneously

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, text, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate several text objects in matplotlib at the same time.  I have a 3-D numpy array (`arrow_data`) of data which stores the index of a unicode arrow which I need to plot (text for all unicode arrows are stored in a list `arrows`).  The first and second dimension of this np.array indicate the location on a grid where this arrow needs to be plotted and the 3rd dimension is the 'time' dimension over which I need to update the plot (ie the arrows change through time over the 3d dimension of the array).

Below is the code I have for animating these arrows through 'time' using a loop, but I don't see how I can make a collection of text objects, as I can with other matplotlib functions like scatter, and then collectively (and efficiently) update the `set_text` property of each of them.  The loop over the 'time' variable is fine but I'd prefer to not use a loop over the grid of text objects if possible.

Any thoughts on how to do this without the double nested loop?

Thanks.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib
matplotlib.interactive(True)

arrows = [u'\u2190', u'\u2196', u'\u2191', u'\u2197', u'\u2192', u'\u2198', u'\u2193', u'\u2199']
rest_time = 0.25
steps = 20

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot([0,4],[0,4], c = 'white')
objs = [[[] for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        objs[i][j] = ax.text(i+0.5,j+0.5, arrows[i], ha = 'center', va = 'center')
fig.canvas.draw()

arrow_data = np.random.randint(0,len(arrows), (4,4,steps))

for t in range(arrow_data.shape[2]):
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            objs[i][j].set_text(arrows[arrow_data[i,j,t]])
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(rest_time)
```

Comment: Looping over the text objects isn't the slow part here. The slow part is the call to `fig.canvas.draw()`.  If things are running reasonably fast, I wouldn't change it.  If they're not, you can use blitting (i.e. drawing and refreshing only a portion of the plot) instead.  The `matplotlib.animate` framework gives a bit simpler method of doing this if you don't want to handle the blitting manually.

Comment: @JoeKington perhaps you can post your comment as an answer...